# How to fit different recommendation models into a system

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I am trying to build a recommendation engine with different sets of models. Is their any way i can keep these models as plug and play type or make these models depend on the other. I am looking an algorithm.

I recently read about the "gradient boosted decision trees", will it be useful in my case and if so, they how should i implement it?

Making a recommendation engine is making my brain go blur. :-). Help.

Answer (score 0):

Gradient tree boosting could be plug and play. But you would have to have a fixed tree structure and remember classifiers' performance for each branch. Otherwise you would have to retrain your ensemble each time you add or remove a classifier.

For plug and play ensemble I would just go with [bagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating).